# Get specific value from js code after parsing

Tags: javascript

I have a json like this in my test.json -

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "XXX",
"playList": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Song A"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "updated": "{\"UPDATED_TIMES\": 20, \"UPDATE_PEOPLE\": 10}",
      "name": "Song B"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want a javascript code that parses this json and returns me the value of `UPDATED_TIMES`. Also sometimes the `updated` key might not be there. So how do I check it as well.

Comment: Can you please show what you've tried to accomplish the task?

Answer (score 0):

This will return an array of updated times (I doubt this is what you want as you miss the information on the song the value is associated with, but it answers your question).

```
function getUpdateTimes(obj) {
  return obj.playList.filter(song => { 
  // filters the playList array for elements that have no updated field
    return 'updated' in song})
    .map(filteredSong => filteredSong.updated.UPDATED_TIMES)
}
```

Comment: Where is 'song'

Comment: @alexgosel998 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: It seems to work but when I print song.updated.UPDATED_TIMES it is undefined

Comment: What did you change actually?

Comment: @alexgosel998 maybe it wasn't showing, you also have a demo here (I edited it to an object as your copy pasted JSON wasn't valid for the repl):
https://repl.it/repls/UnwrittenSoftDisks